# Non-Blocking Concurrent Queue with offer and flush

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Non-Blocking Concurrent Queue with offer and flush

I'd need an unbounded non-blocking concurrent queue with basically only 2 operations:

- offer : atomically inserts the specified item at the tail of this queue;
- flush : takes all the items present in that moment in the queue and start processing them one by one following the insertion order. More specifically what has to be atomic is only this "takeAll" operation that will be the very first operation of the flush. All items offered to the queue after the takeAll will be inserted and then processed only by a another subsequent flush.

The goal is the consumer has a single CAS operation on the takeAll and can then iterate the elements in the list without going through a CAS operation per read. Further we already own the Node (Entry) as this is needed to store some other immutable state. The new node can take the HEAD as a constructor argument, creating a single direction linked list.

Does exist in literature a queue with these characteristics?

Comment: I disagree. Java native ConcurrentLinkedQueue already guarantee insertion order without blocking. I only miss that takeAll operation (and I am not interested in all other features provided by the ConcurrentLinkedQueue)

Comment: on flush, just replace `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, in which you add elements, with a new empty instance, and return first that was replaced.

Comment: why does your flush require a single CAS operation?

Comment: If you can ensure one consumer, then you can avoid the consumer CAS altogether (see [SingleConsumerQueue](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/SingleConsumerQueue.java))

Comment: How is flush different to drainTo(Collection)?

Comment: I want to avoid the copy of all items in the queue in a different data structure before processing them. Anyway where is that drainTo(Collection) method defined? I cannot find it.

Comment: Its defined on `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: @BenManes unfortunately all standard `BlockingQueue` implementations use locking mechanism. OP wants his queue to be non-blocking...

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yep, I was just mentioning where it is defined, but hadn't suggesting it.

Answer (score 13):

Here you go:

```
public class FunkyQueue<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<Node<T>> _tail = new AtomicReference<Node<T>>();

    public void offer(T t) {
        while(true) {
            Node<T> tail = _tail.get();
            Node<T> newTail = new Node<T>(t, tail);
            if(_tail.compareAndSet(tail, newTail)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<T> takeAll() {
        Node<T> tail = _tail.getAndSet(null);

        LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
        while(tail != null) {
            list.addFirst(tail.get());
            tail = tail.getPrevious();
        }

        return list;
    }

    private static final class Node<T>
    {
        private final T _obj;
        private Node<T> _prev;

        private Node(T obj, Node<T> prev) {
            _obj = obj;
            _prev = prev;            
        }

        public T get() {
            return _obj;
        }

        public Node<T> getPrevious() {
            return _prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was writing exactly this. The only problem I see is the additional memory usage in takeAll, but I think this isn't really an issue :)

Comment: Actually, I think you can avoid the O(n^2) list construction in takeAll by also storing _next in Node<T>.

Comment: O(n^2)?  it's only O(n).  and you can't store _next without a lot more complexity.

Comment: `list.add(0, tail.get())` is O(n).

Comment: I thought a similar solution but the cost of reversing the list in that way can easily overcome (by far) the cost of a lock.

Comment: Using a `LinkedList` with `ListIterator` would give you O(1) inserts.

Comment: @JuanLopes - ah, now i see.  if the lists are long enough for that to be a concern, then you can just use LinkedList (as Mick mentioned).  despite the theoretical inefficiency, ArrayList is often more efficient than LinkedList in practice due to things like better cache locality and lower memory footprint.

Comment: @MarioFusco - your statement doesn't make sense.  if that is the case, then just use simple locking or a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  (although i fail to see how a simple iteration of a list would be worse than the same amount of CAS operations (or a lock if blocking is a concern)).

Comment: Updated to use LinkedList for O(1) inserts.

Comment: @jtahlborn Are you sure? What happens if the queue contains 100K items when you do the takeAll (as it can easily happen in my use case)? A "simple" iteration of 100K items adding all of them to a brand new list will have a big cost, trust me.

Comment: @MarioFusco - in which case, your desire for a "non blocking" version probably doesn't make sense and you should be using some form of locking (as i also mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: @jtahlborn please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29794410/3459206 Based on your algorithm, I used skip levels to speed up list traversal

Answer (score 5):

**Given**: [nice implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29779790/3459206), that requires a single CAS for both `offer()` and `takeAll()`.

**Problem**: long `takeAll()` execution, since it needs full traversal of single-linked list in opposite direction.

**Solution**: create additional skip levels on nodes. For mentioned figures (N ~ 100K) two levels would be enough, thus reducing number of steps in `takeAll()` to ~150.

Based on mentioned implementation, `Node` class:

```
public static final class Node<T> {

    private final T value;
    private Node<T> prev, prevL1, prevL2;
    private Node<T> next, nextL1, nextL2;

    private Node(T obj, Node<T> prev, long c) {
        value = obj;
        this.prev = prev;  
        // level 1 to skip 64 nodes, level 2 to skip 64^2 nodes
        // c is a value from some global addition counter, that
        // is not required to be atomic with `offer()`
        prevL1 = (c & (64 - 1) == 0) ? prev : prev.prevL1;
        prevL2 = (c & (64 * 64 - 1) == 0) ? prev : prev.prevL2;
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }

    public Node<T> findHead() {
        // see below
    }

    public Node<T> next() {
        // see below
    }
}
```

`FunkyQueue#offer()` method:

```
public void offer(T t) {
    long c = counter.incrementAndGet();  
    for(;;) {
        Node<T> oldTail = tail.get();
        Node<T> newTail = new Node<T>(t, oldTail, c);
        if (tail.compareAndSet(oldTail, newTail)) 
            break;
    }
}
```

`FunkyQueue#takeAll()` would now return the head of the list:

```
public Node<T> takeAll() {
    return tail.getAndSet(null).findHead();
}
```

It calls `Node#findHead()`, which now can use skip levels to speed up backward traversal:

```
private Node<T> findHead() {

     Node<T> n = this;
     while (n.prevL2 != null) {  // <- traverse back on L2, assigning `next` nodes
         n.prevL2.nextL2 = n;
         n = n.prevL2; 
     }
     while (n.prevL1 != null) {  // <- the same for L1
         n.prevL1.nextL1 = n;
         n = n.prev1;
     }
     while (n.prev != null) {    // <- the same for L0
         n.prev.next = n;
         n = n.prev;
     }
     return n;
}
```

And finally, `Node#next()`:

```
public Node<T> next() {

    if (this.next == null && this.nextL1 == null && this.nextL2 == null)       
        throw new IllegalStateException("No such element");

    Node<T> n;
    if (this.next == null) {         // L0 is not traversed yet
        if (this.nextL1 == null) {   // the same for L1
            n = this.nextL2;         // step forward on L2
            while (n != this) {      // traverse on L1
                n.prevL1.nextL1 = n;
                n = n.prevL1;
            }
        }  
        n = this.nextL1;             // step forward on L1
        while (n != this) {          // traverse on L0
            n.prev.next = n;
            n = n.prev;
        }
    }
    return this.next;
}
```

I suppose the main idea is clear. Applying some refactoring, it is possible to make `Node#findHead()` and thus `FunkyQueue#takeAll()` operate in O(log N), and `Node#next()` in O(1) at average.

---

P.S. if one notices some error or bad grammar, please edit.

Comment: I would probably implement an [optimistic lock-free queues](http://people.csail.mit.edu/edya/publications/OptimisticFIFOQueue-journal.pdf) and CAS it to empty. Then either traverse the links with a supplied lambda or return an unmodifiable `Collection` view. The only traversal that is necessary is for the consumption of the elements.

Comment: @BenManes jtahlborn obtains the head in O(N), I obtain it in O(log N), if you would do this in O(1), it would be great.

Comment: very interesting implementation.  i haven't worked through this fully yet, but one thing i noticed is that the counter used in offer() could be out of order on insert.  unsure if that will break the list order or not.

Comment: @jtahlborn as I mentioned, counter doesn't need to be consistent at all. It only acts as level generator in a skip list. It's a kind of indexer which indexes every 64th node on level 1, and every 4096th on level 2. Assignment is performed using only single *current tail* node, so there is no chance for them to be linked to nodes that are thrown away.

Comment: While your findHead is O(log N) and your next is ~ O(1), i believe your overall performance (assuming a complete traversal of the list after a call to getAll) is really O(2N), you could achieve the same result with less memory overhead by just traversing the list backwards once in getAll() and assigning the next values (and reducing the memory overhead significantly).  I think the only overall perf gain in this impl vs. that would be if the caller did not fully traverse the result of getAll().

Comment: @jtahlborn absolutely agree, overall traversing and memory consumption will be worse. This is a price for getting the head of the queue quickly.

Comment: i don't understand the point of getting to the head quickly if the overall time to utilize the list is the same?

Comment: @jtahlborn well... I don't criticize your implementation, I find it clear an effective. I just modified it for the case when time to access the head is critical. It certainly may be the point. We can only guess, since OP doesn't disclose its usage.

Comment: that's a fair point.  as i said above, it could be useful if the caller may not use all the data.

Comment: @BenManes do you have some progress with the implementation? Bounty expires soon, I need someone to award it to.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Oh, I didn't notice the bounty. I wrote a prototype but haven't had time to worked out the race conditions.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Added a link to my implementation. It seems to work, but needs more testing.

Answer (score 1):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) uses the [Michael & Scott algorithm](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf) and could be adapted to provide this method. The returned collection would be an unmodifiable view of the removed nodes for traversal. That would look something like,

```
public Collection<E> drain() {
  for (;;) {
    Node<E> h = head;
    Node<E> t = tail;

    if (h == t) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    } else if (casHead(h, t)) {
      return new CollectionView<E>(h, t);
    }
  }
}
```

Forking a collection isn't very fun, so instead I [implemented](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/520ee5ba17778d503ba1fa753ddc43d7bb59ca40/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/ConcurrentLinkedLazyQueue.java) the [Mozes & Shavit algorithm](http://people.csail.mit.edu/edya/publications/OptimisticFIFOQueue-journal.pdf) for an optimistic queue (a faster alternative). This is enhanced with a backoff arena to combine concurrent additions to reduce contention caused by multiple producers.